# How many Tor exit nodes are there?

Tags: tor

On average (as I do understand that servers go on and off the network, etc.) how many [Tor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_%28anonymity_network%29) exit nodes are there in service at any given time?  (It is probably going to be an informed estimate.)

Comment: related: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/7055/how-to-find-the-current-number-of-tor-relays-exit-nodes-in-entire-tor-network

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out "Torstat": http://torstatus.blutmagie.de/ The table at the bottom of the page (Aggregate Network Statistic Summary) shows you the current number of exit nodes.

Comment: As of 18 Jan 2017 it shows 7190 "Number of Routers in Cache," and 862 "Total Number of 'Exit' Routers". See here for an image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tpl2x.png.

Comment: This website is no longer online.https://metrics.torproject.org/relayflags.html as Johan pointed out is up & running.

Answer (score 17):

This is now graphed by the Torproject at https://metrics.torproject.org/relayflags.html 
(826 exit nodes today).

Answer (score -1):

IMO, easier to check the lists exit nodes here - https://check.torproject.org/torbulkexitlist